# Twitter Bootstrap - multiple button group list submenues issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm playing around with an admin theme I bought, but I'm having problems with drop down lists

here is the code in question:

```
      <div id="user-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
     <ul class="nav btn-toolbar">
        <li class="btn btn-inverse dropdown" id="menu-accounts"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#menu-accounts" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="icon icon-user"></i> <span class="text">Accounts</span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="sFindAccount" title="" href="#">Find Account</a></li>
              <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
              <li><a class="sNewAccount" title="" href="#">New Account</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="btn btn-inverse dropdown" id="menu-services"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#menu-services" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="icon icon-th-list"></i> <span class="text">Services</span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="sFindService" title="" href="#">Find Service</a></li>
              <li><a class="sNewService" title="" href="#">New Service</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="btn btn-inverse"><a title="" href="#"><i class="icon icon-cog"></i> <span class="text">Settings</span></a></li>
        <li class="btn btn-inverse"><a title="" href="login.html"><i class="icon icon-share-alt"></i> <span class="text">Logout</span></a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

I also activate jquery for $(".dropdown-menu").dropdown()

Now. The account menu works as expected, you can click on it and it drops down - if you click anywhere else, then it disappears (expected). However, if you click on the service menu, then click on the account menu it stays. It doesn't disappears when you click other menu items (like the account menu does).

I can't seem to find anyone who is having this problem - and anything I find is related to not having the Jquery i mentioned above activated.

Any help on this would be great. If you answer and you have a PHP question - just provide the link to your question and I'd be glad to help where I can.

Comment: For those willing to help here is a JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ufixin/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it, you don't need that data-target... that is breaking the JS for some reason I am not 100% sure yet, still looking into it.

Just remove those and you will have it working like this.

here is it fixed: http://jsbin.com/ufixin/4/edit

Comment: Legend... Spent over an hour starring at the screen removing everything EXCEPT that. Cheers buddy.